# Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone Extension Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, nuget

Really simple question:

> Where do you find Extension Manager in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone?

I'm trying to install the NuGet extension but.. Just can't seem to find extension manager, looking under the tools menu where I expect it but.. nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: you mean package manager console???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Extension Manager is not supported in Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone, so you can't find it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, how exactly does one then go about and install the Windows Phone Toolkit in Visual Studio? Or can you only install it on Silverlight?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 supported extensions via Extension Manager. The Windows Phone Toolkit can be installed via the NuGet package manager which is installed as an extension and can be downloaded from http://nuget.org..

Comment: So you're saying that I shouldn't use "Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone", I should use the normal "Visual Studio 2010", install NuGet as  an extension, then install the Windows Phone Toolkit that way?

Comment: I think I see the issue here, to develop apps for Windows Phone you need to install the Windows Phone SDK, found here:


https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk


If you have an existing copy of Visual Studio this will install on top of it, otherwise it'll install an "Express" version of Visual Studio.  Once installed you can install NuGet and from there you can install the Windows Phone Toolkit which is an open source collection of common Windows Phone controls.  The SDK is needed to build apps, the Toolkit is a nice a little collection of controls to help make building apps easier.

Answer (score 1):

NuGet is the extension manager that is built into Visual Studio 2012 and is also available for Visual Studio 2010 as a seperate download.  It's easy to intall and can be downloaded from [nuget.org](http://nuget.org).  Once it's installed adding the Windows Phone Toolkit is as easy as right-clicking on your project and selecting "Managed NuGet packages...".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I wondering though, is Visual Studio 2012 on stable release to-date?

Comment: @DeanGrobler I'm using Visual Studio 2012 for a few months, everything works fine for me. But I suggust you using the Visual Studio 2010 before the Windows Phone 8 SDK is officially released.

Answer (score 0):

Extension manager is found in Menubar->Tools

Comment: sorry dude,am not sure u might have the same problem check the link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/fbe1dd2e-b2f2-4a39-b9f1-91cf94fe92a5